# Compile GN-based projects with modified compiler flags

Tags: gn, cflags

The build system that V8 uses is not straightforward. Assume I desired to add `-save-temps` to the build flags to keep all intermediate files produced during compilation. Where would I specify this information? Do you specify it in a particular command? Does it have to be added to a special build configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

(This question isn't really about V8, but rather the [GN build system](https://gn.googlesource.com/gn/).)

GN is intentionally designed to take all build configuration from files (which you can check into git/etc for reproducible builds), rather than command-line flags and environment variables. So any extra compiler flags also have to be specified via files. Specifically, you can edit any of the `cflags = ...` or `cflags += ...` definitions that apply to the compilation units in question. In case of V8, you can e.g. add your flag to the `cflags = []` initialization [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/BUILD.gn#957), or you could make a similar change in `build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn`, which will also affect any dependencies.

Comment: Is there an easier way? Perhaps one from the GN method that is intended to provide the functionality I seek without editing "core" configuration files or scripts?

Comment: I don't think there's another way -- as I said, specifying build configuration via files is an intentional choice that GN has made. (I also think that changing 1 line in 1 file qualifies as "easy".)